# Cant display an image via PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I have a strange problem, when I try to enter the source of an image tag using PHP it shows me the following error in the inspector

```
<img src=(unknown) alt="">
```

this code fragment gives me the correct url, checked by seeing the CPanel and pasting and copying the address,but when I try to enter it via php the image is not shown

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id); 
//echo($image[0]);
?>
<img src="<?php $image[0]; ?>" alt="">
```

The next thing I did was an echo of image[0] and it gave me the url of the image, I copied it and pasted it in the  tag and that's when it showed me the image

```
<img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/957a...150x150.jpg" alt="">
```

I saw the page in Incognito Window and I did not show the image either.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need echo the image, try this:

```
<php
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id ); 
//echo( $image[0] );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: thanks, now I will slowly dissapear in a sea of shame

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the URL of the image, use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`. It saves you having to do the `[0]` thing:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>" alt="">
```

However, if you want to output an image tag for an attachment, you're much better off using `wp_get_attachment_image()`:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' );
```

This will give you the full `<img>` tag, but including the alt text, width & height attributes, and `srcset` attribute. The alt text in particular is important.